# Why I can't traverse this linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having a hard time to understand why I'm having an infinite loop while I try to traverse a linked list I made to practice :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct noeud {
    int val;
    struct noeud *next;
} noeud;

noeud* add_first(noeud* head, int val){
    noeud* p = malloc(sizeof(noeud));
    if(p == NULL){
        puts("ERROR ALLOCATING NODE ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else{
        p->val = val;
        p->next = head;

    }
    return p;
}


void discover(noeud* head){
    noeud* current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("---|%d|-|%p|---",current->val, current->next);
        current = head->next;
    }

}

int main(){

    noeud* head = malloc(sizeof(noeud));
    head->next = NULL;
    head = add_first(head, 5);
    head = add_first(head, 4);
    head = add_first(head, 3);
    head = add_first(head, 8);
    discover(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what I did : I created a function like push to add nodes at first, each one will link to the previous one, I'm updating head to take the first node each time I push something new .

Then I'm just trying to print the result and the adresse of the next node, to do so, I used a while loop and I would verify for the NULL condition, I believe the problem is that after updating head, then `head->next` is not NULL anymore, but I can't really find a way to keep the last element point to null .

Comment: `current = head->next;` --> `current = current->next;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, it worked, could you post it as an answer so I hit solved ?

Comment: @EugeneSh this doesn't look correct to me, I think it will not print the node with value 8

Comment: That was correct, it did .

Comment: It did print all nodes?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what he meant. It's my bad sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your function, you copied the head pointer to a stack variable, `noeud* current = head;`, but then inside the while loop you assign the stack variable to the next member of head, `current = head->next;`.

This will just lead to continuous assignment to the same `next` address and never moves `current` just switch it to this:

```
current = current->next;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks strange how you allocate memory for a "head node", you don't need to do that. All you need is a single HEAD pointer like so `noeud* head = NULL;`.

Your `main()` becomes:

```
int main(){

    noeud* head = NULL;

    head = add_first(head, 5);
    head = add_first(head, 4);
    head = add_first(head, 3);
    head = add_first(head, 8);

    discover(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Then you have to modify your printing function as per the Josh Weinstein answer:

```
void discover(noeud* head){
    noeud* current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("---|%d|-|%p|---\n",current->val, current->next);
        current = current->next;
    }

}
```